# Represent DateTime in OLE Automation Format In C

Tags: c#, c, datetime, time

I'm new to C and I'm looking for a way to represent a datetime value in OLE Automation format in C, something like DateTime.TOADate() that we have in C#

To represent my DateTime, I have been looking at using the struct tm from time.h, however I have a question about this too. I need to represent the milliseconds part as well but from looking at the documentation it appears to only break it down as far as the seconds part?

Thanks

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221646(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @HansPassant I did come across this but this only deals with system time whereas I have timestamps from the past that I need to convert

Comment: "time stamps from the past" does not help me help you.  You must describe the format they are in.

Comment: @HansPassant Here is an example I have, this is the DateTime format: 12/07/2016 17:57:33 and I need to represent it as: 42563.789969907404

Comment: That just looks like a string.  It knows [how to do that as well](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221395(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for the link, I will look into it